# Crossbrowser equivalent of explicitOriginalTarget event parameter

Tags: javascript, events, cross-browser, scriptaculous

Does anyone know of crossbrowser equivalent of explicitOriginalTarget event parameter? This parameter is Mozilla specific and it gives me the element that caused the blur. Let's say i have a text input and a link on my page. Text input has the focus. If I click on the link, text input's blur event gives me the link element in Firefox via  explicitOriginalTarget parameter.

I am extending Autocompleter.Base's onBlur method to not hide the search results when search field loses focus to given elements. By default, onBlur method hides if search-field loses focus to any element.

```
Autocompleter.Base.prototype.onBlur = Autocompleter.Base.prototype.onBlur.wrap(
function(origfunc, ev) {
    var newTargetElement = (ev.explicitOriginalTarget.nodeType == 3 ? ev.explicitOriginalTarget.parentNode: ev.explicitOriginalTarget); // FIX: This works only in firefox because of event's explicitOriginalTarget property
    var callOriginalFunction = true;
    for (i = 0; i < obj.options.validEventElements.length; i++) {
        if ($(obj.options.validEventElements[i])) {
            if (newTargetElement.descendantOf($(obj.options.validEventElements[i])) == true || newTargetElement == $(obj.options.validEventElements[i])) {
                callOriginalFunction = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (callOriginalFunction) {
        return origFunc(ev);
    }
}
);


new Ajax.Autocompleter("search-field", "search-results", 'getresults.php', { validEventElements: ['search-field','result-count'] });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no equivalent to explicitOriginalTarget in any of the other than Gecko-based browsers. In Gecko this is an internal property and it is not supposed to be used by an application developer (maybe by XBL binding writers).

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Maybe I should start writing my own method using event delegation instead of trying to extend onBlur method of Autocompleter. With event delegation and using some global variables I can fix this.

Answer (score 4):

The rough equivalent for Mozilla's .explicitOriginalTarget in IE is document.activeElement.  I say rough equivalent because it will sometimes return a slightly different level in the DOM node tree depending on your circumstance, but it's still a useful tool.  Unfortunately I'm still looking for a Google Chrome equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

2015 update... you can use event.relatedTarget on Chrome. Such a basic thing, hopefully the other browsers will follow...

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like Firefox doesn't have or expose .explicitOriginalTarget anymore, nor have they implemented .relatedTarget yet, as of July 2015. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=962251

Comment: @JudahHimango Firefox 55 still supports `explicitOriginalTarget`. Regarding `relatedTarget`, it's not the same at all.

Answer (score 3):

IE `srcElement` does not contain the same element as FF `explicitOriginalTarget`. It's easy to see this: if you have a button field with `onClick` action and a text field with `onChange` action, change the text field and move the cursor directly to the button and click it. At that point the IE `srcElement` will be the text field, but the `explicitOriginalTarget` will be the button field. For IE, you can get the x,y coordinates of the mouse click from the `event.x` and `event.y` properties.

Unfortunately, the Chrome browser provides neither the `explicitOriginalTarget` nor the mouse coordinates for the click. You are left to your own devices to figure out where the `onChange` event was fired from. To do this, judicious use of `mousemove` and `mouseout` events can provide mouse tracking which can then be inspected in the `onChange` handler.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is more designed for extension writers than for Web design...

I would watch the blur/focus events on both targets (or potential targets) and share their information.
The exact implementation might depend on the purpose, actually.

Comment: I also thought watching blur/focus events on both targets but if Firefox has a specific parameter (explicitOriginalTarget) for that, maybe the other browsers have too. Maybe not a parameter but a hack.

Answer (score 0):

For IE you can use `srcElement`, and forced it.

```
if( !selectTag.explicitOriginalTarget )
    selectTag.explicitOriginalTarget = selectTag.srcElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of form submit events, you can use the [`submitter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter) property in all modern browser (as of 2022).

```js
let form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  let submitter = event.submitter; //either a form input or a submit button
});
```