# How is the default submit button on an HTML form determined?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, standards

If a form is submitted but not by any specific button, such as

- by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- using `HTMLFormElement.submit()` in JS

how is a browser supposed to determine which of multiple submit buttons, if any, to use as the one pressed?

This is significant on two levels:

- calling an `onclick` event handler attached to a submit button
- the data sent back to the web server

My experiments so far have shown that:

- when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, Firefox, Opera and Safari use the first submit button in the form
- when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, IE uses either the first submit button or none at all depending on conditions I haven't been able to figure out
- all these browsers use none at all for a JS submit

What does the standard say?

If it would help, here's my test code (the PHP is relevant only to my method of testing, not to my question itself)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Get</h1>
<dl>
<?php foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) echo "<dt>$k</dt><dd>$v</dd>"; ?>
</dl>

<h1>Post</h1>
<dl>
<?php foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) echo "<dt>$k</dt><dd>$v</dd>"; ?>
</dl>

<form name="theForm" method="<?php echo isset($_GET['method']) ? $_GET['method'] : 'get'; ?>" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="method" />
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Button 1" onclick="alert('Button 1'); return true" />
    <input type="text" name="stuff" />
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Button 2" onclick="alert('Button 2'); return true" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="document.theForm.submit();" />
</form>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

If you submit the form via JavaScript (i.e., `formElement.submit()` or anything equivalent), then *none* of the submit buttons are considered successful and none of their values are included in the submitted data.  (Note that if you submit the form by using `submitElement.click()` then the submit that you had a reference to is considered active; this doesn't really fall under the remit of your question since here the submit button is unambiguous but I thought I'd include it for people who read the first part and wonder how to make a submit button successful via JavaScript form submission.  Of course, the form's onsubmit handlers will still fire this way whereas they wouldn't via `form.submit()` so that's another kettle of fish...)

If the form is submitted by hitting Enter while in a non-textarea field, then it's actually down to the user agent to decide what it wants here. [The specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-button) don't say anything about submitting a form using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key while in a text entry field (if you tab to a button and activate it using space or whatever, then there's no problem as that specific submit button is unambiguously used).  All it says is that a form must be submitted when a submit button is activated. It's not even a requirement that hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> in e.g. a text input will submit the form.

I believe that Internet Explorer chooses the submit button that appears first in the source; I have a feeling that Firefox and Opera choose the button with the lowest tabindex, falling back to the first defined if nothing else is defined.  There's also some complications regarding whether the submits have a non-default value attribute IIRC.

The point to take away is that there is no defined standard for what happens here and it's entirely at the whim of the browser - so as far as possible in whatever you're doing, try to avoid relying on any particular behaviour.  If you really must know, you can probably find out the behaviour of the various browser versions, but when I investigated this a while back there were some quite convoluted conditions (which of course are subject to change with new browser versions) and I'd advise you to avoid it if possible!

Comment: Re para 2: My basic question was whether there's anything in any spec to the effect of "If the browser provides any means of submitting a form without specifying a submit control...".  But I gather from David's reply that there isn't.

My point about IE was that sometimes pressing Enter submits a form and doesn't set any submit button.  A consequence is that, if you have multiple forms submitting to the same script, you can't rely on submit buttons to distinguish them.  This came up in the project I'm working on.

Comment: Very useful first paragraph bracket section - thanks.

Answer (score 81):

HTML 4 does not make it explicit. HTML 5 [specifies that the first submit button must be the default](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#implicit-submission):

> 4.10.21.2 Implicit submission
>
> A `form` element's **default button** is the first [submit button](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#concept-submit-button) in [tree order](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-tree-order) whose [form owner](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-owner) is that `form` element.
>
> If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly
> (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key while a text
> control is [focused](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focused) implicitly submits the form), then doing so for a
> form, whose [default button](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#default-button) has [activation behavior](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#eventtarget-activation-behavior) and is not
> [disabled](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-disabled), must cause the user agent to [fire a `click` event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#fire-a-click-event) at that
> [default button](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#default-button).

If you want to influence which one is "first" while maintaining the visual order then there are a couple of approaches you could take.

An off-screen, unfocusable button.

```css
.hidden-default {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="text">
  <button name="submit" value="wanted" class="hidden-default" tabindex="-1"></button>
  <button name="submit" value="not wanted">Not the default</button>
  <button name="submit" value="wanted">Looks like the default</button>
</form>
```

Flexbox order:

```css
.ordering {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.ordering button {
    order: 2;
}

.ordering button + button {
    order: 1;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="text">
  <div class="ordering">
    <button name="submit" value="wanted">First in document order</button>
    <button name="submit" value="not wanted">Second in document order</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @user5480949 — The default value for the `type` attribute is `submit`. This answer is about which submit button is the default, not about the different ways you can create submit buttons.

Comment: I feel confused about what a "submit button" is in spec. A `<input type=submit />`? Or also `<button type=submit />`?

Answer (score 67):

[Andrezj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925334/how-is-the-default-submit-button-on-an-html-form-determined/925387#925387) pretty much got it nailed... but here's an easy cross-browser solution.

Take a form like this:

```
<form>
    <input/>
    <button type="submit" value="some non-default action"/>
    <button type="submit" value="another non-default action"/>
    <button type="submit" value="yet another non-default action"/>

    <button type="submit" value="default action"/>
</form>
```

and refactor to this:

```
<form>
    <input/>

    <button style="overflow: visible !important; height: 0 !important; width: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important; border: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; display: block !important;" type="submit" value="default action"/>

    <button type="submit" value="some non-default action"/>
    <button type="submit" value="another non-default action"/>
    <button type="submit" value="yet another non-default action"/>
    <button type="submit" value="still another non-default action"/>

    <button type="submit" value="default action"/>
</form>
```

Since the [W3C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) specification indicates multiple submit buttons are valid, but omits guidance as to how the user-agent should handle them, the browser manufacturers are left to implement as they see fit. I've found they'll either submit the first submit button in the form, or submit the next submit button after the form field that currently has focus.

Unfortunately, simply adding a style of **display: none;** won't work because the W3C spec indicates any hidden element should be excluded from user interactions. So hide it in plain sight instead!

Above is an example of the solution I ended up putting into production. Hitting the enter key triggers the default form submission is behavior as expected, even when other non-default values are present and precede the default submit button in the DOM. Bonus for mouse/keyboard interaction with explicit user inputs while avoiding JavaScript handlers.

Note: tabbing through the form will not display focus for any visual element yet will still cause the invisible button to be selected. To avoid this issue, simply set tabindex attributes accordingly and omit a tabindex attribute on the invisible submit button.  While it may seem out of place to promote these styles to !important, they *should* prevent any framework or existing button styles from interfering with this fix. Also, those inline styles are definitely poor form, but we're proving concepts here... not writing production code.

Comment: Thanks. Stumbled across the **display: none** problem as well. Instead of minimizing the button you could also move it out of the page by surronding it with a `<div style="position: fixed; left: -1000px; top: -1000px />`. Just one more thing to concern: Just minimizing or moving away the button from the page flow with CSS might bring up WAI issues, because screen readers will still see the default button.

Comment: this worked for me, thanks. I had to add this for the button  border:none; to make it complitely disapear

Comment: You can just set the tabindex attribute of the hidden button to -1

Comment: What's that `<input/>` up there for?

Comment: @lunakid  <input /> is there to show the placement of input-level form elements (textarea, radio, checkboxes, inputs, etc) in relation to the submit buttons.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see. :) And that `overflow: visible`? Is it really needed? *(BTW, funny to see how bad fortune swiped me back to web dev. again and now I find myself here after those 4+ years just to continue exactly where we left off! :) So, hi there James, hope you, and all the others, are well! :) )*

Comment: Hello again! I haven't tested lately, but at the time of writing: yes.

`overflow: visible` is required because an element needs to be "visible" to the DOM in order to receive user input.

Answer (score 26):

This can now be solved using [Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox):

#### HTML

```
<form>
    <h1>My Form</h1>
    <label for="text">Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text"/>

    <!-- Put the elements in reverse order -->
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button>Ok</button> <!-- Our default action is first -->
        <button>Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### CSS

```
.form-actions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse; /* Reverse the elements inside */
}
```

#### Explanation

Using Flexbox, we can reverse the order of the elements in a container that uses `display: flex` by also using the CSS rule: `flex-direction: row-reverse`. This requires no CSS or hidden elements. For older browsers that do not support Flexbox, they still get a workable solution but the elements will not be reversed.

#### Demo

http://codepen.io/Godwin/pen/rLVKjm

Comment: Bootstrap has also a convinient class for it: `flex-row-reverse`

Answer (score 17):

I think this post would help if someone wants to do it with jQuery:

http://greatwebguy.com/programming/dom/default-html-button-submit-on-enter-with-jquery/

The basic solution is:

```
$(function() {
    $("form input").keypress(function (e) {
    if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
        $('input[type=submit].default').click();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
    });
});
```

And another I liked was:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("form input, form select").live('keypress', function (e) {
        if ($(this).parents('form').find('button[type=submit].default, input[type=submit].default').length <= 0)
            return true;

        if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
            $(this).parents('form').find('button[type=submit].default, input[type=submit].default').click();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: [jQuery.Event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) always has its `.wich` attribute. Also no need to fall back to DOM's `.keyCode` (or `.charCode` for that matter).

Comment: Another issue regarding jQuery here is the unneccessary double query. Since there is no need to return true, additionally, the jQuery version gets really clear and short on integrating reductions advised by Arjan before.

Comment: I used keydown instead of keypress (avoid waiting for keyup) and I added `e.preventDefault();` into the beginning of this function to avoid execution of the "real" default button. Works really well.

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 7):

I had a form with 11 submit buttons on it, and it would always use the first submit button when the user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I read elsewhere that it is not a good idea (bad practice) to have more than one submit button on a form, and the best way to do this is have the button you want as default, as the only submit button on the form. The other buttons should be made into "TYPE=BUTTON" and an onClick event added that calls your own submit routine in JavaScript. Something like this:

```
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
function validform()
{
  // Do whatever you need to validate the form, and return true or false accordingly
}

function mjsubmit()
{
  if (validform()) { document.form1.submit(); return true;}
  return false;
}
</SCRIPT>
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON NAME="button1" VALUE="button1" onClick="document.form1.submitvalue='button1'; return mjsubmit();">
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON NAME="button2" VALUE="button2" onClick="document.form1.submitvalue='button2'; return mjsubmit();">
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="button3" VALUE="button3" onClick="document.form1.submitvalue='button3'; return validform();">
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON NAME="button4" VALUE="button4" onClick="document.form1.submitvalue='button4'; return mjsubmit();">
```

Here, button3 is the default, and although you are programmatically submitting the form with the other buttons, the *mjsubmit* routine validates them.

Comment: Bad idea. Your form won't work with JS disabled. JS ought to be used unobtrusively.

Comment: Very few browsers have JS turned off by default, even the ones on iPods! On the form I was citing, JS off would render it useless! So much hinges on JS running.

Comment: Turned off by default or not, those who have JS disabled ought not to have to switch it on just to get around such a silly little snag as this.

Comment: what kind of form has 11 submit buttons?? (*curiosity*)

Comment: Additionally your code sucks. `language` needs to die, the proper attribute is `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: @mhenry1384: there are a lot of reasons why you should NOT restrict your user in any way (when possible). Your statement is the same like saying users who use IE6 need to die - There are still users being dependent on which browser (and setting) they use, e.g. in a lot of companies. So in my opinion, one should ALWAYS consider users restricted to IE6 and JS disabled - at least by providing a workaround for them.

Comment: The biggest reason I see validating unobtrusive Javascript is that *obtrusive* Javascript tends to be fiddly.  I'm not sure how to qualify what I'm thinking, but when I see pages absolutely reliant on JS, I'm also betting I can do some tricky stuff with my DOM and do something unintended on the server.

Comment: @mhenry1384 That's like saying people who wear glasses, use wheelchairs, etc. need to die.

Comment: Another method involves styling a copy of the desired submit button so that its absolute position is off-screen, and making sure it's the first button declared on the form, despite its invisibility. It is difficult to validate form entries without JavaScript unless it's done at server end.

Answer (score 3):

```
<form onsubmit="alert('submit');return false;">
    <input name="username">
    <input name="password" type="password">
    <button onclick="if(document.activeElement === this){alert('button 1');}else{default_submit.click();}return false;">button 1</button>
    <button onclick="if(document.activeElement === this){alert('button 2');}else{default_submit.click();}return false;">button 2</button>
    <input id="default_submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

If you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> from text input, then the button will not become focused. Then we ignore this click and click the default submit instead, but if you click the button by mouse, it will be focused, then we apply this click.

Demo: https://codepen.io/remon-reffat/pen/mdRaXbp

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the same question since I had a submit button in the middle of the form which redirected submit to another page, like so:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="this.form.action = '#another_page'">More</button>
```

When the user pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, this button was clicked instead of another submit button.

So I did some primitive tests by creating a form with multiple submit buttons and different visibility options and an onclick event alerting which button was clicked: https://jsfiddle.net/aqfy51om/1/

Browsers and OSes I used for testing:

#### Windows

- Google Chrome 43 (come on Google Search :D)
- Mozilla Firefox 38
- [Internet Explorer 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_11)
- [Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) 30.0

#### OS X

- Google Chrome 43
- [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) 7.1.6

Most of these browsers clicked the very first button despite the visibility options applied **except Internet Explorer and Safari** which clicked the third button, which is "visible" inside a "hidden" container:

```
<div style="width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="alert('Hidden submit button #3 was clicked');">Hidden submit button #3</button>
</div>
```

So my suggestion, which I'm going to use myself, is:

If your form has multiple submit buttons with different meanings, then include a submit button with the default action at the beginning of the form which is either:

1. Fully visible
2. Wrapped in a container with `style="width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;"`

Another option might be to offset the button (still at the beginning of the from) `style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; top: -9999px;"`, just tried it in Internet Explorer - worked , but I have no idea what else it can screw up, for example printing..

Answer (score 1):

From your comments:

> A consequence is that, if you have
> multiple forms submitting to the same
> script, you can't rely on submit
> buttons to distinguish them.

I drop an `<input type="hidden" value="form_name" />` into each form.

If submitting with JavaScript: add submit events to forms, not click events to their buttons. Savvy users don't touch their mouse very often.

Comment: Indeed, but that begs this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541869/determine-which-element-submitted-a-form-from-within-onsubmit

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple submit buttons in a single form and a user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to submit the form from a text field, this code overrides default functionality, by calling the submit event on the form from the key press event.  Here is that code:

```
$('form input').keypress(function(e){

    if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)){
        $(e.target).closest('form').submit(); return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
});
```

Comment: Simple and fixes the issue

Answer (score 1):

Strange that the first button <kbd>Enter</kbd> goes always to the first button regardless is visible or not, e.g. using jQuery `show/hide()`. Adding attribute `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` prevent receiving the <kbd>Enter</kbd> submit button completely. It's a problem for example when adjusting the *Insert/Edit+Delete* button visibility in record dialogs. I found it less hackish and simple placing *Edit* in front of *Insert*:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="update">Update</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="insert">Insert</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="delete">Delete</button>
```

And use JavaScript code:

```
$("#formId button[type='submit'][name='action'][value!='insert']").hide().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("#formId button[type='submit'][name='action'][value='insert']").show().removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

My recipe:

```
<form>
    <input type=hidden name=action value=login> <!-- The magic! -->

    <input type=text name=email>
    <input type=text name=password>

    <input type=submit name=action value=login>
    <input type=submit name=action value="forgot password">
</form>
```

It will send the default hidden field if none of the buttons are 'clicked'.

If one is clicked, it has preference and its value is passed.

Comment: But is this behaviour specified by the standard?  And can browsers be trusted to implement it correctly?

Comment: good question. i've tested it to work on all A browsers (from yui browser matrix) and it's the most consitent i could get in real life (regardless of what the standards specify)

Comment: @yellowandred what happens? will take a look later

Comment: my mistake, I changed {type="hidden"} and i didnot notice the same 'name' values.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in IE11 or Fx30. The value is always set to the hidden value.

Comment: This does not have the desired behavior in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox. The "action" parameter *always* contains the value "login" for implicit submissions. This would be an elegant solution, but cannot be relied upon.

Comment: @ClintPachl all modern browsers will either send, if you click forgot password on the example: `?action=forgot_password` or `?action=login&action=forgot_password` it is still workable... though not as elegant as before :(

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I've used is to just have one button in the form, and fake the other buttons.

Here's an example:

```
<form>
  <label for="amount">Amount of items</label>
  <input id="amount" type="text" name="amount" />
  <span id="checkStock" class="buttonish">Check stock</span>
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="order">Place order</button>
</form>
```

I then style the span elements to look like a button. A JavaScript listener observes the span and performs the desired operation once clicked.

It’s not necessarily right for all situations, but at least it’s pretty easy to do.

Comment: What's the fallback for users who have JS disabled?

Comment: Users with JS disabled won't be able to use the internet, it's as simple as that nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

From the [HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls):

> If a form contains more than one submit button, only the activated
> submit button is successful.

This means that given more than one submit button and none activated (clicked), none should be successful.

And I'd argue this makes sense:

Imagine a huge form with multiple submit-buttons. At the top, there is a "delete this record"-button, then lots of inputs follow and at the bottom there is an "update this record"-button. A user hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> while in a field at the bottom of the form would never suspect that he/she implicitly hits the "delete this record" from the top.

Therefore I think it is not a good idea to use the first or any other button it the user does not define (click) one. Nevertheless, browsers are doing it of course.

Answer (score -1):

To determine what button is pressed when hitting enter, you can mark it up with `type="submit"`, and the other buttons mark them with `type="button"`. For example:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

<sub>Sorry, when writing this answer I was thinking about submit buttons in the general sense. The answer below is not about multiple `type="submit"` buttons, as it leaves only one `type="submit"` and change the other to `type="button"`. I leave the answer here as reference in case helps someone that can change the `type` in their form.</sub>

Comment: Type "button" does not cause the form to submit.  It's used only to trigger client-side scripts.

Comment: exactly, that's why the browser skips it when you hit enter, and the one with type "submit" gets executed. You can use the one with type "button" to do anything else on click for example. Please remove the negative vote.

Comment: The question was about multiple **submit** buttons.

Comment: My example is totally valid for multiple submit buttons. The one with type "submit" is the one determined by the browser to act as pressed (which is what the question was about). Then with the other button you can use it as submit button as well using JavaScript events like the onClick event that you have in your example. So my answer is relevant and don't deserve a down vote. Please remove it.

Comment: **multiple** submit buttons. The **one** with type "submit" - you have contradicted yourself there.

Comment: If your point was to suggest removing the ambiguity by making only one of them type "submit" and using JavaScript to implement the other buttons, then this is a duplicate of graphic's reply and as such has already been dismissed as a bad idea.

Comment: The **one** with type "submit" + the **one** with type "button" === multiple buttons. So no contradictions there. And yes, my point was that. But that is a bad idea for you or for JS disabled supporters doesn't mean that is a bad idea for everyone. My app requires JS to work, so it worked for me.

Comment: Now that I read the thread again, I understand what you mean. Yes your question is about multiple type="submit" buttons, and my solution leaves only 1 type="submit". Sorry about the confusion, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: <button>s can still trigger form submit behavior.