# Enter Key for Login Form

Tags: forms, authentication, key, enter

I have a search form and a login form on my website. When the enter button is pressed when the login form has focus, the search runs instead of the login. Is there a way to fix this?

I've already tried using a panel around the login form and use defaultbutton, but the loginview errors when I do this.

Comment: are you referring to ASP.NET login controls?

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting up a keypress event on your login form. Off the top of my head, something like

```
$('#loginForm').keypress(function (e) {
  if(e.keyCode=='13') //Keycode for "Return"
     $('#login').click();
  }
});
```

should work, assuming you give appropriate IDs to the elements involved.

Answer (score 0):

could you try adding attributes at run time like this

```
Login loginControl = (Login)lvLoginView.FindControl("logLogin"); 
TextBox tbUserName = (TextBox)loginControl.FindControl("UserName");
TextBox tbPassword = (TextBox)loginControl.FindControl("Password");
Button loginButton = (Button)loginControl.FindControl("LoginButton");  
tbUserName.Attributes["onKeyPress"] = "KeyDownHandler('" + loginButton.ClientID + "')";
tbPassword.Attributes["onKeyPress"] = "KeyDownHandler('" + loginButton.ClientID + "')";
```

and some JS:

```
function KeyDownHandler(btn){  
// process only the Enter key  
if (event.keyCode == 13)  {    
// cancel the default submit  
  event.returnValue = false;  
  event.cancel = true;   
  var obj = document.getElementById(btn);   
  obj.click();  
}}
```

**UPDATE**

Auto-converted to VB.NET courtesy of telerik

```
Dim loginControl As Login = DirectCast(lvLoginView.FindControl("logLogin"), Login)
Dim tbUserName As TextBox = DirectCast(loginControl.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox)
Dim tbPassword As TextBox = DirectCast(loginControl.FindControl("Password"), TextBox)
Dim loginButton As Button = DirectCast(loginControl.FindControl("LoginButton"), Button)
tbUserName.Attributes("onKeyPress") = "KeyDownHandler('" + loginButton.ClientID + "')"
tbPassword.Attributes("onKeyPress") = "KeyDownHandler('" + loginButton.ClientID + "')"
```

Comment: By runtime do you mean form load? Because that's all done in VB.

Comment: Okay, well the code that I put should be quite easy to convert into VB, its just C#

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about HTML, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925334/how-is-the-default-submit-button-on-an-html-form-determined/925387#925387) suggests tab order (learn more about that [here](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/html/controll_tab_order.php)) is relevant or the order in which the forms were created, the behavior depending on the user agent.