# Jquery show and hide causing form submit

Tags: jquery, events, form-submit

Ok, so i have a form and it has several groups of fields, like a facebook account settings edit, to show when you click it.

```
  <form id="test" action="#" method="POST">
    <ul class="items">
        <li>
            <button class="show-content-button">Show</button>
            <div class="form-content ui-helper-hidden">
                Hello
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="show-content-button">Show</button>
            <div class="form-content ui-helper-hidden">
                Hello
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="show-content-button">Show</button>
            <div class="form-content ui-helper-hidden">
                Hello
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("form#test").submit(function() {
            alert("hello i have been submitted");
        })
        $(".show-content-button").click(function() {
            var $button = $(this);
            if ($button.text() === "Show") {
                $(".form-content", $button.parent()).fadeIn(400);
                $button.html("Hide");
            } else if ($button.text() === "Hide") {
                $(".form-content", $button.parent()).fadeOut(200);
                $button.html("Show");
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

When i click one of the shows, it causes the form to be submitted... why?  I can fix this problem by returning false on the button click event, BUT, i feel that this is a hack and not a solution.  Anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that by default (in browsers other than IE) the `type` of the button is `submit` - for your use case, you want it to be `button`. Adding an attribute `type="button"`, should fix it.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/haTX7/) showing the effect of [the lack of] the `type` attribute for `<button>`s. You'll have to see the network activity in your browser's development tool (Firebug in FF, Developer Tools in Chrome)

Comment: You are correct my friend.  That is strange default behavior, kind of stupid.  Ohh well.  I like my button way because it makes html styling easy within the button.  Thanks for the correct solution!!

Answer (score 2):

`event.preventDefault()` should be what you're looking for:  http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("form#test").submit(function() {
        alert("hello i have been submitted");
    })
    $(".show-content-button").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $button = $(this);
        if ($button.text() === "Show") {
            $(".form-content", $button.parent()).fadeIn(400);
            $button.html("Hide");
        } else if ($button.text() === "Hide") {
            $(".form-content", $button.parent()).fadeOut(200);
            $button.html("Show");
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, i put in my comments that i put a return false and it did the trick.  I am not asking how to fix it, i am asking why?  Why does showing content based off a button click that has NOTHING to do with a form submit causes the form to submit?

Comment: @Michael See my answer - it has to do with the default `type` for `<button>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `return false;` it stops form submitting

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("form#test").submit(function() {
            alert("hello i have been submitted");
        })
        $(".show-content-button").click(function() {
            var $button = $(this);
            if ($button.text() === "Show") {
                $(".form-content", $button.parent()).fadeIn(400);
                $button.html("Hide");
            } else if ($button.text() === "Hide") {
                $(".form-content", $button.parent()).fadeOut(200);
                $button.html("Show");
            }
    return false;
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Read my comment above please! :)  thanks for answer and giving your attempt, but maybe i was not clear about my question

Answer (score 0):

I added your code to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SYR9y/) (linked if you want to stuff around some more), however even if I remove the click event for the button, the submit still fires. It looks like in the absense of a proper submit button, HTML picks one of the buttons. (I can't find this behavior specific to buttons in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-button)).

As the other "answerers" have now suggested since I'm a slow typer, you should use preventDefault.

You may find this useful - [How is the default submit button on an HTML form determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925334/how-is-the-default-submit-button-on-an-html-form-determined)

Comment: even when i add a submit button the problem persists.  and it does not pick 1 button, it picks all 3 buttons

Comment: Bah, I should've tested more than the first one when I was playing around with it!