# PHP Script doesn't work on my form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a HTML form, and a php script for saving the elements into a .txt file.
Here's my form:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Send us a message</h2>
    <form id="contact-form" action="myscript.php" method="POST">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
                <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" />
                <input name="subject" id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="submit_contact" value="Send message" />
                <div id="msg" class="message"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>                     
</div>
```

And my php script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['comment'])) {
    $data ='Name : ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" . 'E-Mail : ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" . 'Website : ' . $_POST['subject'] . "\n" . 'Comment : ' . $_POST['comment'] . "\n" . '----------------------------------------------------------------' . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('comments.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
    if($ret === false) {
        echo "<script>alert('Failure!');</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('Success!');</script>";
    }
    }
    else {
      echo "<script>alert('Fill in The Form Please !');</script>";
    }
```

When I fill the form and press submit, nothing happens actually.
But when I remove the DIV tags it works.

Here are my full codes:
[My HTML code](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7006557/) and [my CSS code](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7006562/)

Comment: Which `<div>` tags are you referring to?

Comment: So it is not about the PHP script but your HTML or maybe some JS?

Comment: @relentless , i mean all of them . i removed all of them and tried again and it worked fine.

Comment: Do you have more HTML around it that you are not showing? Sounds a bit odd that a few HTML tags stop your form from submitting.

Comment: @putvande , yes i think it's not about php , but i don't know which part has problem .

Comment: Maybe post the html that DOES work.

Comment: @putvande , yes. i puted it at the end of question:

Comment: @dg988 , that's this code . i just removed the <div> tags. that's it.

Comment: Well, with all due respect, don't trust yourself. That's why you're asking us.

Comment: did you check the values are posted in `myscript.php`

Comment: Your CSS file have very important errors on } . so some browsers may delete form inputs. You can del CSS file or change internet browser to test it.

Comment: if thats your whole php file, you should get an exception because you're missing that ending bracket of your if clause.

Comment: Does it submit when you tab to the submit button and hit enter? Does the submit button visually change `onmousedown`?

Comment: @dg988 The Valid Form that does work : http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7006617/     there is some js files , do you need to see them?

Comment: help us, to help you dude. HELP US, to HELP YOU.

Comment: @razhial , sorry , it's ok in my own file.

Comment: You've got some funky css going on. My best guess is that something is z-indexed on top of your submit button. Can you say whether tabbing to the submit button and hitting enter works?

Comment: @dg988 i Cant understand ! can you explain more ?!

Comment: If you focus on (click so the outside is highlighted and you can type into) one of the text boxes (inputs), and then press the "tab" key on your keyboard, it should move to the next text box. if you do this again, it will eventually move to the "submit" button. Once there, press the "enter" key. Does it work?

Comment: @dg988 he has a submit button, it should submit if he presses enter while any input control has focus.

Comment: @Snowburnt He has multiple inputs. This prevents "enter" submitting.

Comment: @Snowburnt No, sorry. I think you're right. The submit should negate that, right?

Comment: @dg988 it does work in the "without <div>" code.

Comment: @dg988 if it's in a form tag, pressing enter will perform the submit function

Comment: @Snowburnt ...unless there multiple inputs, and no submit button. Got it.

Comment: @dg988 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925334/how-is-the-default-submit-button-on-an-html-form-determined the first answer here pretty much clears it up. Multiple inputs are irrelevant, but the function of the enter key within a form in a nontextarea is determined by the browser, there's no actual spec for it.

Comment: @Snowburnt Without a submit button, multiple inputs are indeed relevant. One input + enter will submit. Two inputs + enter will do nothing. Any number of inputs + submit button + enter will submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code and the HTML as posted. Included your css.

You have an extra brace in the script.

This code shows the form and creates the 'comments.txt' file.

Added test to ensure all the fields are entered

PHP 5.3.18 on windows XP.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['myscript'])) { // the form was submitted...


    if(   isset($_POST['name'])    && !empty($_POST['name'])
       && isset($_POST['email'])   && !empty($_POST['email'])
       && isset($_POST['subject']) && !empty($_POST['subject'])
       && isset($_POST['comment']) && !empty($_POST['comment'])) {

        $data ='Name : ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" . 'E-Mail : ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" . 'Website : '
                . $_POST['subject'] . "\n" . 'Comment : ' . $_POST['comment'] . "\n"
                . '----------------------------------------------------------------' . "\n";
        $ret = file_put_contents('comments.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
        if($ret === false) {
            echo "<script>alert('Failure!');</script>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<script>alert('Success!');</script>";
        }
    }
    else {
      echo "<script>alert('Fill in The Form Please !');</script>";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Q22077564</title>
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="Q22077564.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
  </head>

<body>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Send us a message</h2>
    <form id="contact-form" action="myscript.php" method="POST">
      <!-- add hidden field so that we know the form came in! -->
      <input type="hidden" name="myscript"  value="myscript" />;
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
                <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" />
                <input name="subject" id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="submit_contact" value="Send message" />
                <div id="msg" class="message"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . it works but when i run it , an alert shows "success" . and it mustn't show that at the first place. what should i do ?

Comment: Ah! OK give me a few minutes and i will fix it!

Comment: @ShaPesar `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { // form has been posted } else { // diplay form, no past has been made yet }`

Comment: added a hidden field to detect the form being submitted. Used your CSS. The code appends entries into the comment.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['comment'])) {
$data ='Name : ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" . 'E-Mail : ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" . 'Website : ' . $_POST['subject'] . "\n" . 'Comment : ' . $_POST['comment'] . "\n" . '----------------------------------------------------------------' . "\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('comments.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
if($ret === false) {
    echo "<script>alert('Failure!');</script>";
}
else {
    echo "<script>alert('Success!');</script>";
}
}
else {
  echo "<script>alert('Fill in The Form Please !');</script>";
} **}**//not your answer but you should remove this one right
```