# Multiple react form inputs disables the onSubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I have this very simple example that works as expected:
https://jsfiddle.net/x1suxu9h/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { msg: '' }
  },
  onSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ msg: 'submitted' })
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" />
        <div>{this.state.msg}</div>
      </form>
    )
  }
});
```

**However**, when adding another form field, the onSubmit is not triggered anymore when pressing the enter key: https://jsfiddle.net/nyvt6506/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { msg: '' }
  },
  onSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ msg: 'submitted' })
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <div>{this.state.msg}</div>
      </form>
    )
  }
});
```

Am I missing the obvious here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting a form by pressing enter without a submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button)

Comment: just add submit button into your form

Comment: It's not a React based problem. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925334/how-is-the-default-submit-button-on-an-html-form-determined

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normally just pressing enter while focusing a form element doesn't submit it, you would use something to specifically submit it (like a submit button or an event handler to submit it upon pressing enter)

However, by default, if there's only ONE text input in the whole form then pressing enter submits it (it's some HTML specification). However, it's good to manually handle form submission.

So if you add this:

```
<button type='submit' />
```

to your form, whether there's one or two or 50 text inputs it will still submit

Comment: *Spot on*. note to future readers: if you preventDefault on click event for the button, the submithandler won’t trigger when pressing enter either: https://jsfiddle.net/3mL50u9c/ :/

Answer (score 2):

Including an input of type "submit" will suffice for the form submission

```
<input type="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onKeyPress` instead of `onSubmit` as a workaround, something like this

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { msg: '' }
  },
  onSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.currentTarget); // <-- Form
    this.setState({ msg: 'submitted' })
  },
  onKeyPress: function(e) {
    if(e.key === 'Enter')
        this.onSubmit(e);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <form onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <div>{this.state.msg}</div>
      </form>
    )
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyvt6506/3/)