# How to not try to trigger disabled buttons on pressing enter by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, default, keypress

I have a react app, and when I was pressing enter it was triggering a hidden button, rather than the button that was showed.
So I set it to disabled if hidden.

But the problem now is that "on enter" nothing happens when that button is disabled. I imagine the default behaviour is to still try to trigger the closest button on the page (regardless of if it's disabled or not).

Is there a way to alter this behaviour, or a different attribute (other than / side by side) the disabled attribute.

I know this can be done instead:

[How to trigger a button click on Enter in React](https://reactgo.com/react-trigger-button-click/)

But I would prefer a cleaner way to monitoring which button should be triggered on enter at a specific time

Comment: I think you need to give us more context. How was the hidden button being triggered? Did it have an `onkeypress` listener attached to it? If so, how is it different from the article you linked? Also, what do you mean by 'which button should be triggered on enter at a specific time'? Do you need to invoke different button clicks depending on user state? Please specify.

Comment: I don't have an onkeypress, it's default behaviour. I just pressed enter and it triggered a button I have on the page. But that button was hidden at that time, so I didn't want that to happen. So I disabled it so that wouldn't happen. But then enter did nothing (instead of triggering the other button)

Comment: By this 'which button should be triggered on enter at a specific time' I mean, if button a is hidden, don't trigger it. trigger the only viewable button.

Comment: I have an input field above the two buttons. I was pressing enter from there. This also has no onkeypress

Comment: Pressing `Enter` anywhere on the page does not trigger `onclick` of a button by default, however, if the button is inside a `form`, and the user is `focused` within the form. [You can see the above behaviour here](https://codepen.io/c_sharp_/pen/dyJjJoo). Pressing `Enter` while focused on the first `input` does not trigger the first `button`, but doing so while focused on the second `input` triggers the second `button`.

Comment: My situation is two buttons inside a form. The input is focused and enter is pressed. but the first button is hidden and disabled. How to make it trigger the second button?

Comment: example: https://codepen.io/Kieran95/pen/ZEvjqXW

Comment: In the codepen link you gave, I'm getting different behaviours depending on the browser. `Button 3` gets clicked in Safari, and no button gets clicked in Chrome. Will [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box) help you solve your case?

Comment: I think I found the answer for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167557/6217413. Thank you for your help