# Many submit button for one form

Tags: jquery

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/xFvrV/2/

```
<form id="formTest" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="textTest"/><br>
    <input id="submitButtonDraft" type="submit" value="Save Draft" /><br>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formTest").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('toto');
    });
});
```

How to know which button submit the form? and display it in the **alert()**

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine which element submitted a form from within onsubmit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541869/determine-which-element-submitted-a-form-from-within-onsubmit)

Comment: In terms of design it's bad form design if you _care_ about which button submitted the form. You really should have two forms instead if the submission button is important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep track of the button pressed: http://jsfiddle.net/xFvrV/9/.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formTest").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // get data from form's data
        alert($(this).data('submitbutton').attr('value'));
    });

    $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
        // save as data on form's .data
        $(this).parent().data('submitbutton', $(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to store it as `.data` on `$("#formTest")` instead.

Answer (score -4):

If they are of `type=submit` they will submit the form.

So in your case **both** of the buttons will submit the form.

Comment: He's asking how to determine _programmatically_ which button was pressed; he already knows that either are candidates.