# Two ways to process jQuery submitted form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with button **A** and button **B**. It's sent by a jQuery function called clicking on one of the buttons. At the end of this long function which is checking prerequisites, the form is sent using this line:

```
$('#wlform').submit();
```

I want to adjust this code to send something to be able to distinguish which button was pressed. Something in JavaScript similar to `<input type="submit" name="submitbutton1"/>`

Comment: what does button A and B do for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to get which button was clicked upon form submission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission)

Comment: A publishes the data live, B saves it as draft.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328892/value-of-submit-button-clicked

Answer (score 0):

Just give to the hidden input the value of the button id attribute. You could do something similar to this (before the submit statement):

```
$('input[type=hidden]').val($(this).attr('id'));
```

Where *$(this)* is the button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Provide us with some code?

I think you're talking about two buttons that both should have their own ID's. You could try and catch the ID attributes after you click them;

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Or change 'id' into 'name' if you want to get that value.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use a javascrit `click` event to execute your javascript functions.

In javascript, you can add a hidden input to your form :

```
$(...).click(function() {
    ... // Your code

    var clicked_button = $(this);
    $('#wlform').append($('<input type="hidden" name="clicked-button"/>').val(clicked_button.attr('id'));

    $('#wlform').submit();
});
```

With that, the id of the clicked_button will be sent with the form.

Comment: There's no need to append the hidden input. Better to place it on the html file.

Comment: That's right. You can place an empty hidden field in the html and update it with the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked, so I've put something together from these on my own. I've added a hidden input field, `clicked-button` as you suggested. Then when calling my `precheck_submit` function, I pass another parameter (`c`) for storing which has been clicked. In the `precheck_submit` function I added `$('#clicked-button').val(c);`. It works. Anyways, thanks for your efforts.