# Detect which submit button was clicked

Tags: jquery

I know this question sounds a lot like a bunch of others that are out there, but I swear I can't find the right solution anywhere. I have a legacy form that has multiple submit buttons. If one is clicked, I need to do a bit of client-side validation and potentially stop the submit. If the other is clicked, I don't need to do this validation.

What I'm finding is that if I create a `.submit()` handler, I can't seem to access which button was actually clicked. On the other hand, if I capture the `.click()` event of the button I need to worry about, then I can't prevent the form from submitting via `.preventDefault()` (or `.stopImmediatePropagation()`).

Here's the most recent iteration of the code that attempts to use the buttons `.click()` handler:

```
$('#nextButton').click( function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault(); // The form submits anyway (which kind of makes sense)
  // return false also doesn't prevent the submission

  // If any session question is unanswered, abort
  /* $('#registrants input:text[id$="Answer"]').each( function( i, input ) {
    if( $.trim( $(input).val() ) == '' ) {
      submit = false;
    }
  });*/
});
```

What am I missing here? There *has* to be a way to do this and it seems like it should be fairly simple, but I'll be damned if I've had any luck at all.

Thanks.

Comment: if there is more than one submits why u use same id for them. Use different ids and bind click functions to each submit button so no need to find out which submit is clicked.

Comment: @Sedat -- they don't have the same id. The one I care about is `#nextButton` where I'm capturing the click. What I can't seem to do is prevent the submission.

Comment: @RobWilkerson - `preventDefault` should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/DQNSb/1/

Comment: @JamesAllardice -- Very strange. I wonder why it's not working for me. I'll check my jQuery version...

Comment: You can use click handlers to detect the button and then `$('form').bind('submit', 'false');` to prevent the default action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps:
http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/09/09/intercept-a-form-submit-with-jquery-and-prevent-or-allow.aspx

Basically what it says is to check the button ID in the form submit() handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/4wnyY/5/

Comment: Using explicitOriginalTarget as suggested, is not cross-browser compatible. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179826/crossbrowser-equivalent-of-explicitoriginaltarget-event-parameter

Answer (score 9):

Maybe something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/4wnyY/3/

```
var which;

$("input").click(function () {
    which = $(this).attr("id");
});
$("#form").submit(function () {
    if (which == "button2") {
        return false; // if "button2" submit clicked - prevent submission
    }
});
```

The main issue with this code would be browser compatibility - i don't know if all browsers work the same, if the click event will be caught before the submit one. I remember that it was different on one version of IE, maybe 7. But it's fixable.

Answer (score 0):

@Przemek has the right answer and approach for this.

I would only add to insure you put your function inside the `$(document).ready(function(){}` if you are doing a form submission.

Works across all browsers.
See below for the solution that worked for me based on Przemek's example:

```
    //Used to hold the button name of what was clicked
        var which;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("button").click(function () {
                which = $(this).attr("id");
                //alert("Button Clicked Name");
            });

            $('#searchForm').submit(function (evt) {
                if (btnName = "btnSave") {
                    // do something for the Save option
                } else {
                    // do something different for the Submit or Save and Close option
                }
}
}
```